# Why is my decorator breaking for this Flask-Login endpoint?

Tags: python, flask, decorator, python-decorators, flask-login

I've figured out how to make Flask-Login authenticate a user based on an LDAP lookup.  Now I'd like to add some authorization to the mix - that is, only allow access to certain endpoints if a user has both logged in **and** belongs to the right groups.

I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it, but I thought I could just add a decoration to an endpoint:

```
@app.route('/top_secret')
@authorize
@login_required
def top_secret():
    return render_template("top_secret.html")
```

and (for now) make a completely pass-through decorator:

```
def authorize(func):
    def newfunc(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return newfunc
```

But running this gives the error:

```
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'top_secret'.
```

while running it without the @authorize decorator works fine.

So I'm not sure where I went wrong.  Can I not decorate endpoints in this way?  And if not, where should the authorization step take place?  (it would have to take place after @login_required has finished what it needs to do)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, yeah, super simple!

```
from functools import wraps


def authorize(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def newfunc(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return newfunc
```

To understand why you need `wraps`, you can do this:

```
 print(top_secret)
```

Once with wraps, and once without. With wraps, you'll see something like this:

```
<function top_secret at 0x7ff165150840>
```

Without it, you'll see:

```
<function authorize.<locals>.newfunc at 0x7f81b8456840>
```

The [documentation for wraps](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) is really good, but basically when you wrap a function by default you lose the docstrings, and attributes, and all the rest. So you lose the `app.route` decoration for your function, so Flask can't figure out how to build the URL.

By adding the `wraps` decorator on there, you restore everything that `app.route` did to your function, and Flask can create your route.

Comment: Wayne, I have a followup question if you have a moment.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36366799/flask-login-breaks-when-my-decorator-accepts-parameters