# Flask-Login breaks when my decorator accepts parameters

Tags: python, flask, decorator, python-decorators, flask-login

Thanks to what I learned from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36361597/why-is-my-decorator-breaking-for-this-flask-login-endpoint), I've been able to make a Flask-Login process with a endpoint like this:

```
@app.route('/top_secret')
@authorize
@login_required
def top_secret():
    return render_template("top_secret.html")
```

and (for now) a completely pass-through "authorize" decorator:

```
from functools import wraps

def authorize(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def newfunc(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return newfunc
```

The `@wraps(func)` call allows Flask to find the endpoint that it's looking for.  So far, so good.

But I want to pass an group name to the "authorize" process, and things go bad when I try to make a decorator that accepts incoming parameters.  This seems to be the correct syntax, unless I'm mistaken:

```
from functools import wraps

def authorize(group=None):
    def real_authorize(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def newfunc(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return newfunc
    return real_authorize
```

But once again the error appears as Flask is unable to figure out the 'top-secret' endpoint:

```
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'top_secret'.
```

I thought perhaps it needed `@wraps(authorize)` decoration right above `def real_authorize(func)`, but that did nothing to help.

Can someone help me figure out where my `@wraps` are going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decorating a function is equivalent to re-binding the name to the result of calling the decorator with the function.

```
@authorize
def top_secret():
    ...

# is equivalent to

def top_secret():
    ...
top_secret = authorize(top_secret)
```

The function you've written is a decorator *factory*: you call it, with an optional argument, to get a decorator.

```
@authorize()
def top_secret():
    ...

# is equivalent to

def top_secret():
    ...
top_secret = authorize()(top_secret)
```

Currently, you're passing `top_secret` as the `group` argument to the factory, so you're never actually creating a route.  Since there's no route, there's no url to build either.